# Focus password textfield in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, focus, uitextfield, uialertview

I'm trying to set the initial focus inside a UIAlertView to the password field, but all I've tried so far didn't work.

I was hoping that this code works but there's a mistake that I can't figure out:

```
- (void)showLoginFormWithUsername:(NSString*)username andPassword:(NSString*)password {
    UIAlertView *loginView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login"
                                                        message:@"Please enter your login data."
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil];

    loginView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;

    // get TextFields
    UITextField *usernameField = [loginView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    UITextField *passwordField = [loginView textFieldAtIndex:1];

    // set text
    if (username)
        usernameField.text = username;
    if (password)
        passwordField.text = password;

    // set focus
    if (usernameField.hasText && !passwordField.hasText)
        [passwordField becomeFirstResponder];

    [loginView show];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't waiting for the alert view to show before you are trying to make it be a responder.    Instead, do this in the `didPresentAlertView:` method.

Comment: Bummer. This does not seem to work for me, on iOS 8.3.